# "Only a finite number" or "only finite number"

Tags: articles, mathematics

The question is contained in the title. I think that the noun "number" is countable, therefore "only a finite number" is correct. However, on mathoverflow the expression "only finite number" is also used, although less often that "only a finite number":

https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=%22only+finite+number%22

https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=%22only+a+finite+number%22

So, which of the following patterns can I use? "There is only a finite number of $f$ such that...", or "There are only finite number of $f$ such that...",
or maybe something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether or not you use the article *a* depends on what exactly you want to say. But, *only finite number* is not correct. I took a peek at a few of the *only finite number* posts from your link, and every one I looked at (which was not anywhere close to all of them, mind) should have been *a finite number*. The fact that the search which includes *a* is ten times more common than the one without hints that *a finite number* is correct.

If you want to say something along the lines of *the available or eligible amount or quantity of X is limited or has an upper bound*, then use *only a finite number of X*. This phrase means, essentially, *a limited quantity of something* and is by far the most commonly used version of this construction.

If you want to say something along the lines of *there are only so many groups or categories of Y* or *unbounded or infinite Y values are not eligible for consideration*, then use *only finite numbers of Y*. Note that *numbers* is plural. This phrase is quite uncommon. If you're unsure which to use, it's more likely that *a finite number* is correct.

Examples:

> There's only a finite number of options.
> Only a finite number of equations model the data.
>
> There are only finite numbers of animals belonging to endangered species alive today.
> The function produces only finite numbers; infinite values are never returned.

Answer (score 2):

*Number* is a singular noun, so you should use *a* before it.

*A finite number* is the right construction. Don't go by connotation; *number* here is a collective noun but still singular.

Answer (score 0):

Ya, what they said...   "Only **a finite number of** oranges..." is the grammatical one. However, from a mathematical perspective it is more polished to say "(there are) **finitely many** (oranges)....", because "only" is redundant when talking about finite-ness.